# How do I transform the list?

Tags: python

Say I have a list like the one below.

```
['butter', 'potatos', 'cheese', ['butter', 'potatos'], ['butter', 'cheese'], ['potatos', 'cheese']]
```

1. How can I change the list to one below where the two words combinations becomes one word?

   ```
   ['butter', 'potatos', 'cheese', 'butter+potatos', 'butter+cheese', 'potatos+cheese']
   ```
2. How can I concatenate each of the term in the transformed list in 1. into a single value with a space between each of the term as below?

   ```
    ['butter potatos cheese butter+potatos butter+cheese potatos+cheese']
   ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flattening a shallow list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this maybe:

```
>>> food = ['butter', 'potatos', 'cheese', ['butter', 'potatos'], ['butter', 'cheese'], ['potatos', 'cheese']]
>>> combinations = [f if type(f) != list else '+'.join(f) for f in food]
>>> combinations
['butter', 'potatos', 'cheese', 'butter+potatos', 'butter+cheese', 'potatos+cheese']
>>> output = ' '.join(combinations)
>>> output
'butter potatos cheese butter+potatos butter+cheese potatos+cheese'
```

The `combinations` is assigned the value of a list comprehension. The comprehension will go through all the values, called `f`, in `food` and check if the item is a list or not. If it's a list, the strings in the list will be `join`ed together, otherwise `f` will be used as-is.

For the output, the `join` method is used again.

Comment: That's why I only have half of your rep. @TimCastelijns :) Ninja edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> say = ['butter', 'potatos', 'cheese', ['butter', 'potatos'], ['butter', 'cheese'], ['potatos', 'cheese']]

>>> # 1
>>> ['+'.join(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x for x in say]
['butter', 'potatos', 'cheese', 'butter+potatos', 'butter+cheese', 'potatos+cheese']
>>> # 2
>>> [' '.join([x if isinstance(x, str) else '+'.join(x) for x in say])]
['butter potatos cheese butter+potatos butter+cheese potatos+cheese']
```

Comment: It is now almost the same as the other one except yours lacks explanation